# rasterio: ImportError: No module named tools.mask

Tags: raster, shapefile, geojson, rasterio

I was trying to rasterize a geojson using rasterio mask function but there is an issue with importing the function

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-37fb1af87d72> in <module>()
      1 import json
      2 import rasterio
----> 3 from rasterio.tools.mask import mask

ImportError: No module named tools.mask
```

rasterio version:  `'1.0a9'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mask` module was moved, after `0.36` if I remember correctly, so you should instead import with:

```
from rasterio.mask import mask
```